# Why does "Points along geometry" in the processing toolbox take so long and is there something faster?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

The [points along geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry) processing algorithm

> Creates points at regular intervals along line or polygon geometries. Created points will have new attributes added for the distance along the geometry and the angle of the line at the point.

I have a LineString with about 230,000 vertices and I picked an interval which would give me about 50,000 points in the end. The process takes 1+ hours (still going.) All I need are the equidistant points. I suspect that the extra "angle of the line at the point" is taking a lot of the time. The documentation does not give any visibility into how the algorithm works. Does anyone know if this is correct?

And is there a plugin which is faster for getting equidistant points? In the end I will convert them back into a linestring using the [points to path](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path) tool. So if these is something that returns a reduced LineString instead of Points layer I could use that as well.

---

**QGIS verion 3.10.5, Windows*

Comment: Is your line feature multipart?

Comment: @Jeremiah: Have you tried the "Split lines by maximum length" tool in the Processing Toolbox? That seems to do in a single step what you're trying to achieve with the combination of "Points along geometry" and "Points to path".

Comment: @AWGIS: It is a single linestring. I will try breaking it up and report if there is an improvement.

Comment: @Jake: If there is a way build a linestring from the sublinestring end points then "split lines by maximum length" might be an option. I do not think that tool, *per se*, is what I need.

Comment: @AWGIS: Indeed. Splitting the linestring up using "split lines by maximum distance" (thanks @Jake!) into ~500 sublinestrings I was able to get my ~50,000 points in around a second.

Comment: @JeremiahEngland: Great that you found a solution! I actually misunderstood what "Split lines by maximum distance" does, but it's nice that it ended up being useful anyway. Would you mind posting an answer to your question? I can see this being quite useful to others.

Comment: @JeremiahEngland I'm glad you found a work around.

Comment: @Jake Yes. I would like to put an answer up after I run some more tests this evening to get the actual time complexity formula.